# macターミナルでインストールしたデータを削除する方法を教えてください

Tags: macos, opencv, homebrew

homebrewでopencvをインストールしようとしたのですが、全てのバージョンをインストールすることになってしまい、あまりに容量が大きかったので途中で中断しました　途中までダウンロードしたデータを削除しようとしたのですが、opencvは存在しませんみたいな結果が出てしまい削除できませんでした　もちろんストレージも減っていません　どうすればいいのでしょうか？
また、ターミナルで今までダウンロードしたデータ一覧を見る方法はありますか？

Comment: `brew cleanup -s` でキャッシュを削除すると良いかも知れません。

Comment: @metropolis
そのコードの解説をお願いします　cleanupと -sはそれぞれどのような意味を持つのでしょうか？

Comment: [brew cleanupでMacを掃除してストレージ容量を確保する方法](https://qiita.com/akameco/items/9e5026e892661b75e7b3)